# call php function to put data in a table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a function called displayMenu() that brings data from a table .. this function is inside a php file named functions.php

```
if (isset($_POST['Starters'])) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id=1";
  $sql1= "SELECT cat_name,cat_description FROM category WHERE cat_id=1";
  displayMenu();
}

function displayMenu(){
global $db, $sql,$sql1,$nb;
if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql1)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<h1 class="header">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</h2>';
            echo '<h3 class="content">' . $row['cat_description'] . '</h3>';
        }
    }
}
if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['p_code'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['p_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['p_description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['p_price'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" ;
                            echo '<form class="nbItem" action="order.php" method="post">Nb of items:';
                            echo '<input type="number" name="item"> <button type="submit" class="btn" name="addtocart">Add To Cart</button>';
                            echo '</form>';
                            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

this actually works .. but i want to create the table inside another file called order.php and call this function from this file 
how should i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to include your functions.php file in your order.php file and then call the displayMenu from includes your order file?

### order.php

```
include 'functions.php';

echo displayMenu();
```